# Preposition at the end of a sentence

Tags: american-english, british-english

Regardless of the direction the entrepreneur decides to take the business **in**, it's important to note, it's not a permanent decision.

Can someone explain this? I find it odd to see one part of the sentence ends with  preposition. ( bold )

I think it's grammatically correct, but when to use it?

Comment: The preposition ***in*** is totally unnecessary in your context, so most people probably wouldn't include it anyway. But the idea that there's something inherently *incorrect* about including it (or indeed, ending *any* sentence with a preposition) is completely spurious. Lots of people know that "rule", but *only* because they can take great delight in pointing out that it's [the sort of pedantic nonsense up with which we will not put.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57458/by-whom-vs-who-by#comment109052_57460)

Comment: There is no preposition at the end of that sentence. The preposition is at the end of a *clause*.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as:

> Regardless of the direction **in which** the entrepreneur decides to take the business, it's important to note, it's not a permanent decision.

It's grammatically correct and perfectly acceptable, but you're not alone in finding it odd. This usage is called the *dangling preposition* which is frowned upon by purist linguists.

Comment: It's a complete myth. "Purist linguists" find it quite acceptable. It's only because somebody started a rumour that it wasn't (because of a false parallel between English and Latin), which then caught on and became taught by people (not linguists), that anybody calls it ungrammatical. There is no linguistic foundation for the claim that it's ungrammatical.